# What are the symbols inside of an executable file?

Tags: c, assembly, executable, binaryfiles, machine-code

I always wondered what the symbols inside of executable file mean, for example when I assemble my program, it creates a file, but when I open that file with a text editor, it has these unreadable codes such as ^@^B^A etc. Is this machine code? I thought machine code was like assembly but with binaries.

Comment: The random mess you see is your text editor attempting to convert the individual bytes it finds in the executable to text. The bytes that make up your executable cause the editor to render incomprehensible text and symbols because the contents of the executable is not a text file.. but the bytes the make up the structure of the executable. There are many parts to an executable and there are a few different formats (depending on your platform).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Is it possible to only see the bytes and not the symbols?

Comment: Yes - you do this with [a hex editor](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/). A hex editor will show you both the individual bytes and a textual representation of them.. and will also allow you to manipulate them if you feel the need.

Comment: Alternatively ... I assume you're a programmer ... you could write some code to just read the file byte by byte. This is the equivalent.. obviously.

Comment: It's just because the text editor is trying to display it as text when it's not supposed to be text; when you display it as text it doesn't make sense at all. Like how if you write an `int` with `fprintf` then read it with `fread`, you get garbage.

Comment: they're not text files, so don't read with a text editor

Answer (score 1):

What you see are *unprintable characters* displayed in an ersatz representation.  Basically, the UNIX terminal driver under some circumstances translates non printable characters to sequences of the form `^X` representing the character whose ASCII code is equal to `X` masked with `027` (`0x1f`).  Here is a full table:

```
000 NUL ^@    001 SOH ^A    002 STX ^B    003 ETX ^C
004 EOT ^D    005 ENQ ^E    006 ACK ^F    007 BEL ^G
010 BS  ^H    011 HT  ^I    012 LF  ^J    013 VT  ^K
014 FF  ^L    015 CR  ^M    016 SO  ^N    017 SI  ^O
020 DLE ^P    021 DC1 ^Q    022 DC2 ^R    023 DC3 ^S
024 DC4 ^T    025 NAK ^U    026 SYN ^V    027 ETB ^W
030 CAN ^X    031 EM  ^Y    032 SUB ^Z    033 ESC ^[
034 FS  ^\    035 GS  ^]    036 RS  ^^    037 US  ^_
```

The most common one to see is `^@` representing a byte of all zeroes.  Use a hex dump tool like

```
od -x binary
```

to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

The symbols are misrepresentations of the underlying "machine code", or bytecode (it depends on what kind of executable the file is). In most architectures, code is passed to the CPU in terms of **instructions**, which are several bytes long (depends on the architecture and instruction format). These instructions are encoded in binary, so an instruction could look something like

`001011000011010...1001110010`

Note that this is a made-up example, usually nobody looks at the actual binary or hex encoding of the instruction, but the coded representation of it that has much more meaning to the human eye. That would look something like `mov r0 r3`.

When you run a binary, you can think of the CPU reading the file instruction by instruction and executing it. But when you try to open a binary using a text editor to read it, it tries to interpret the file as text, not as an instruction set. Characters have their own binary encodings (UTF-8, usually), but it often doesn't overlap with the encoding of the instructions. When a string of binary numbers is not matched with an encoding of a valid printable character, it's often matched with an **escape sequence** or various other things, so they show up like these weird symbols.

Note that the lengths of instructions and characters are usually different, so don't expect one symbol to necessarily mean something in "machine code".

Edit: This is a very simplified model of what an executable format can be, only used to explain what the symbols are. Executables are way more complicated than a list of instructions.

Comment: `nobody looks at the actual binary or hex encoding` - I do.. I'm writing a (crappy) JIT compiler.. ;) `you can think of the CPU reading the file instruction by instruction and executing it` - not all executable formats are just flat instructions .. so its a good idea to learn about them if you want to. There are many formats and many have large sections for lots of different things completely separate to code sections.

Comment: Forgot to add a disclaimer saying that it's a very simplified model of what a binary is, thanks for the clarification. Of course the content differs depending on the executable format and you can have sections with arbitrary data, headers and declarations for the processor.

And sorry for dismissing your project and other similar ones, I didn't really know how important bit-by-bit examination could be in today's age.

Comment: No need to apologise for anything at all ... I'm just providing some more information for the OP :)

Comment: I actully look at the hexadecimal encoding quite often as x86 machine code is a variable length instruction set and you can see a lot interesting things from looking at the encoding.